# Install Postgresql on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic (repo removed)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-13, bionic

I'm getting

```
E: The repository 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

on sudo apt update. That means that repo for bionic is not accessible.

In my case for this time I can't upgrade Ubuntu version to a newer one and somehow need to manage that. In this case I suppose I need to remove file from /etc/apt/sources.list.d which contains:

```
deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg main
```

But then how can I have a possibility to install Postgresql on Bionic? Is there any way e.g. to download and install from source?

Comment: "Is there any way e.g. to download and install from source?" Yes. Start [here](https://www.postgresql.org).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks. Downloading from source is more life the last resort. Now I'm just wondering that Postgresql provide that they still support Bionic: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/ but in real - they don't.

Comment: Read [Bionic not suppported](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ZN4OigxPJA236qlg%40msg.df7cb.de). It includes instructions on where it has been moved to.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The packages have been moved to apt-archive.

Point your sources.list entry to

```
deb https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg main
```

See the announcement here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ZN4OigxPJA236qlg%40msg.df7cb.de

Comment: its showing me as deb command not found.... also I am unable to install postgesql 14

Answer (score -1):

The PostgreSQL repo package for Linux seems to be missing. You can install PostgreSQL from source by getting it from the unofficial GitHub repository:[repo](https://github.com/postgres/postgres). You choose the right branch of PostgreSQL depending on the version of PostgreSQL you want, then do installation process from your terminal.

Comment: 1) The source can be found on the [Download](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) page under *Source code* at link [File Browser](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/). 2) This [message](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ZN4OigxPJA236qlg%40msg.df7cb.de) shows you where to get the archived packages for Ubuntu.

Comment: ...And you've verified that if I clone the source code, I'm getting the exact same thing as when I click the download link on postgresql.org? Projects this large rarely work in such a simplistic fashion.

Comment: The source code from GitHub is from postgresql.org, whether you get the same thing or different depends on your installation procedure.